# How to remove and re-add a comma in a string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox on my form that when a button is clicked, it is populated with numbers that are separated by a comma. I have a delete button that will remove the numbers with the comma one at a time. My question is how would I go about re-adding the comma every time i hit the add button, again? I thought i could add the comma in the beginning in an if statement, but its adding two commas, every time I hit the add button, if I delete, then try to re- add.

here is what i have :

```
if textbox1.text = "" then
    textbox1.text = textbox1.text & testNumber(combobox.selecteditem) & ","
else
    textbox1.text = "," & textbox1.text & testnumber(combox.selecteditem)    
end if
```

Comment: Do you want to add `,` (comma) at the end of string? If yes, then: `textbox1.text &= testnumber(combox.selecteditem) & ","` should do the job.

Comment: yes, after every add, the comma should be at the end, and after every delete, the number and comma should be removed. When the user readds the number a comma should appear in front , if there is another number in front, and no comma if nothing in front of it, if there is nothing in the text box

Comment: What `testnumber()` method returns? Can you share its content?

Comment: test number is a function I created to pull the testnumber that matches the description in the combobox. It's from a csv.

Comment: Do you really want to store numbers in a string delimited by comma instead of  `List(Of Integer)`?

Comment: yes, it has to be done this way. I would go with a list of, but they want it as a string.

Comment: @Skywalker84Solo So what if they want a string? Then show them strings in the user interface. But you should still use a more reasonable data structure like a List or Queue internally.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the textbox should only be a **view** of a more appropriate underlying data structure. For example, you might have a `List(Of Integer)` or `Queue(Of Integer)` as a member of your form. When you add or remove an item you first update the collection, then you set the text. For example:

Add:

```
MyList.Add(nextNumber)
textbox1.text = String.Join(","c, MyList)
```

Remove:

```
MyList.RemoveAt(MyList.Count - 1);
textbox1.text = String.Join(","c, MyList)
```

Do this even if they want the ability to update the textbox directly. It's just in this case you must also be able to **validate** and  **parse** the contents of the textbox to recreate the list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, storing numbers in a comma delimited string is pretty strange requirement. I'd suggest to store numbers in a proper data type, such as: `List(Of Integer)`.

Assuming that `testnumber` function returns integer...

```
'define at the top of Form's module:
Private myNumbers As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()

'copy-paste below method to the form's module
Private Function GetCommaSeparatedNumbers() As String
    Return String.Join(",", myNumbers)
End Function

'finally:
'to add number
myNumbers.Add(testnumber(combox.selecteditem))
'to remove number
myNumbers.Remove(testnumber(combox.selecteditem))
'to display numbers
Me.textbox1.Text = GetCommaSeparatedNumbers()
```

If you would like to check out if number already exists on the list, use:

```
If myNumbers.Contains(testnumber(combox.selecteditem)) Then
    'display warning
Else
    'add number
End If
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is initial testing `textbox1.Text = ""` and then, if that is true, it is then doing `textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text & testNumber(combobox.SelectedItem) & ","`, but since `textbox1.Text` is `""` this is the equivalent of:

```
textbox1.Text = "" & testNumber(combobox.SelectedItem) & ","
```

That really means you are adding a comma when you only have one number.

This is what you should be doing:

```
if textbox1.Text = "" then
    textbox1.Text = testNumber(combobox.SelectedItem)
else
    textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text & "," & testnumber(combox.SelectedItem)    
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a number, I'd do it with this line:

```
TextBox1.AppendText(If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, "", ",") & testNumber(ComboBox.SelectedItem))
```

Are numbers being deleted from the beginning or end?...or is a "selected" number from anywhere in the list being deleted?